# Connecting Python to MySQL without using a connector

Tags: python, mysql-connector, pymysql

I have a weird case on my hands. I have a machine that is completely locked. Its a Debian 9 machine and I need to run a Python script that needs to connect to MySQL. The problem is I cant install anything with apt, Python is 3.5.3 and cant be updated and the machine does not have PIP at all. I immediately went to docker but it turns out installing it is out of the question as well.

My question is can I connect to the MySQL DB without using a connector like pymysql? I usually use pymysql/psycopg2 and sqlalchemy for working with database but i cant install any of them in this case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since `pymysql` is pure Python, why can't you download the source from [here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/tree/main/pymysql) and embed it in your project?

Comment: Hm.. you see i didn't even think of it. Ill try that thanks a bunch!

Comment: Does your machine have the `virtualenv` command?  If so you could create your own virtualenv and install pip there.

Comment: This is pretty ridiculous; this is a basic requirement to do your job, surely? I've also been behind corporate restrictions that don't make sense and I've typically made things _worse_ by trying to get around them (I blew up my env vars with `setx` because I found I could execute it). Surely there is a middle ground?

Comment: I used to have to do something like this back in the day when I was deploying Perl apps on a cheap web hosting provider, and I wanted to use various Perl modules. I couldn't install them in the system's Perl lib directory of course, but I could manage my own Perl lib directory in my own account, and add that directory to Perl's `@INC`. It worked for pure Perl modules, but not extensions. It was pretty tedious uploading module after module by ftp...

Comment: It's legitimate for a company to have a policy to lock down the software on a server, so they can prevent software from being installed willy-nilly. Many packages contain vulnerabilities, and they want only known packages installed. So you should consider whether circumventing their policy by uploading packages yourself is going to conflict with the spirit of their policy, even if it doesn't strictly violate their blocking `apt` and `pip`. I'd talk to my manager about it before adding software.